# Laravel- arranging records in ascending and descending order

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a create method in my controller

```
public function create()
{
$image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
foreach($image as $property)
{
    $id = $property->property_id;
}
$image_main = Image::where('property_id', $id)->get();
return view('settings.photos', ['image_array' => $image_main]);
}
```

This is my photos.blade file

```
<form name="asc" action="{{route("settings.photos")}}" method="post" class="text-center">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit"  value="Ascending " class="settings-photos-header2 text-center"/>  |
</form><form name="dec" action="{{route("settings.photos")}}" method="post"  class="text-center">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit"  value= " Descending" class="settings-photos-header2 text-center"/>
</form>
<h2 class="settings-photos-header2 text-center">Photo Gallery</h2>
@foreach ($image_array as $images)
    <div class="image-warp"><img src="{{$images->filename}}"
                                 style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br/><span style="color: #1b1e21">{{$images->description}}</span>
    </form>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Question- How can i make the asc button sort the images in ascending order and des in descending order, is there a way to connect it to my controller, or is there a way to sort them in ascending and descending order through any other means?

Comment: Just a side comment: something looks wrong in that your `foreach(image as property)....` the last `property_id` is picked. Is this intentional?

Comment: The last user that logged in property Id not just the last property id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve the sorting issue but as you have setup your page let me tell you the way you can sort records. Create another action which point to your `settings.photos` route

```
public function settings_photos($property_id) {

  $form = Input::get('submit');
  $orderBy = $form == "Ascending" ? "asc" : "desc";

  # Fetch Images in of Specific Property 
  $list_of_images = Image::where('property_id', $property_id) 
  # Order by Asc/Desc 
  ->sortBy('id', $orderBy)->get(); 

  return view('settings.photos', ['image_array' => $list_of_images]); }
```

Now add `Image->id` to pass in your controller action by form

```css
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432659/laravel-arranging-records-in-ascending-and-descending-order#
```

```html
<form name="asc" action="{{route("settings.photos")}}" method="post" class="text-center">

  @csrf
    
  <input type="image_id" value="{{$id}}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Ascending " class="settings-photos-header2 text-center"/>  |
</form>

<form name="dec" action="{{route("settings.photos")}}" method="post"  class="text-center">
    @csrf
  <input type="image_id" value="{{$id}}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Descending" class="settings-photos-header2 text-center"/>
</form>
```

Now make some changes to your previous Controller code

```
public function create()
{
$image = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
foreach($image as $property)
{
    $id = $property->property_id;
}
$image_main = Image::where('property_id', $id)->get();
return view('settings.photos', ['image_array' => $image_main, 'id' => $id]);
}
```

As I told you there are various way to sort records even by Ajax but I suggest you using your code example. I also did not optimize the code.

Let me know if you have any question.
Thanks

Comment: I want to sort all the images not one, all the images not a particular image, if the for each outputs 2 or more images, the button should sort them

Comment: What do you mean by all images not one? Like you have mentioned query that you fetch images with in the specific Property then following query will return sorted images in the Property.

$image_main = Image::where('property_id', $image_id)->sortBy('id', $orderBy)->get();

Where $image_id is Property->id as per your code sample..

Comment: Yes a a property I'd can have 2 or more images

Comment: O.K, I assume Property has Images and you want to fetch all images other the property in ASC/DESC order. Then do following query

public function settings_photos($property_id) {

 $form = Input::get('submit');
 $orderBy = $form == "Ascending" ? "asc" : "desc";

 # Fetch Images in of Specific Property
 $list_of_images = Image::where('property_id', $property_id)
  # Order by Asc/Desc 
  ->sortBy('id', $orderBy)->get();

  return view('settings.photos', ['image_array' => $list_of_images]);

}

Comment: @nourman this was helpful, but please can you add it to the answer you gave me above for more clarity, just edit and add your comment, Thanks

Comment: @IrueneAdokiye sure